# How can I solve this error in React App? ('Component' is not defined no-undef)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, create-react-app, react-component

**Navbar.js**

```
import React,{ Component } from "react";

class Navbar extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div className="container-fluid">
              <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
                Hetazon
              </a>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**error is***

```
ERROR in [eslint]
src\Component\Navbar.js
  Line 2:22:  'Component' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

I even try **class Navbar extends React.Component** in line 3 **Navbar.js** but the same error was received.

Please help me to solve this error,
I tried so much to solve it but I can't...

Comment: Can you create a code sandbox with the reproducible issue? Try changing `import React, { Component } from "react"` to just `import React from "react"` and then changing your class to extend `React.Component`. What happens in that case?

Comment: I already try it once bt now it works fine thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems eslint has problem with it, and your code is ok

you might need [eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react) package  to be installed